# How do I generate and use a mipmap from separate files?

Tags: opengl

I've got some code that looks like this:

```
_bfTex = new Texture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, true);
_bfTex.Image2D("Textures/sphax/terrain128.png", 0);
_bfTex.Image2D("Textures/sphax/terrain64.png", 1);
_bfTex.Image2D("Textures/sphax/terrain32.png", 2);
_bfTex.Image2D("Textures/sphax/terrain16.png", 3);
_bfTex.Image2D("Textures/sphax/terrain8.png", 4);
_bfTex.Image2D("Textures/sphax/terrain4.png", 5);
_bfTex.Image2D("Textures/sphax/terrain2.png", 6);
_bfTex.Image2D("Textures/sphax/terrain1.png", 7);
_bfTex.SetMinFilter(TextureMinFilter.NearestMipmapNearest);
_bfTex.SetMagFilter(TextureMagFilter.Nearest);
_bfTex.SetParameter(TextureParameterName.TextureWrapS, TextureWrapMode.ClampToEdge);
_bfTex.SetParameter(TextureParameterName.TextureWrapT, TextureWrapMode.ClampToEdge);
```

The `Image2D` function looks like this:

```
public void Image2D(Bitmap bmp, int mipmapReductionLevel = 0)
{
    var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
    var data = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

    GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D, mipmapReductionLevel, PixelInternalFormat.Rgba, data.Width, data.Height, 0,
        OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat.Bgra, PixelType.UnsignedByte, data.Scan0);

    bmp.UnlockBits(data);
}
```

(Code is in C#, but should map 1:1 with C API)

I thought if I called `glTexImage2D` several times with different mipmap reduction levels, I'd then be able to use my texture with mipmapping, but *nothing* seems to be drawn to screen (not even a black texture).

If I just change the min filter to "nearest" everything renders fine as expected, so it's definitely a problem with the mipmapping.

If I use `glGenerateMipmap` to generate my mipmap instead, that works as well.

The reason I want to generate my own mipmap is because it's a spritemap, and it looks like some of the edges of the sprites are bleeding together during the resizing, so I've made separate images which have hard edges between sprites.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought if I called glTexImage2D several times with different mipmap reduction levels, I'd then be able to use my texture with mipmapping

Your assumption is right, this is how you normally explicitly load mipmap levels. Did you test your program with [gDEBugger](http://www.gremedy.com/), to see what's going on?